# iOS jquery .live issue?

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios

I'm using jquery 1.8.3 and I am doing a .live call

```
   $('.ui-state-default').live('click', function(e) {
        $(".upload").show();
    });
```

Using my iPhone iOS 6.1 I cannot click on this dom element.

Why doesn't iOS understand .live?

I switched my code around to this.

```
$('.ui-state-default').bind('click', function(e) {
    $(".upload").show();
});
```

But now I have another issue, is there a way to make iOS understand the first piece of code with .live?

Comment: Are you sure you're using 1.8.3? `.live()` was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9. It should still be there in 1.8. But you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Well I guess I'll have to work out the other issues, with not using .live()

Comment: Use `.on()` as described in the answers.

Comment: You say this is a problem with iOS, have you tried it in a normal browser? i suspect you will have the same issue, and it will be due to the plugin/widget stopping the propagation of the event.

Comment: Chrome still works with .live in jQuery 1.8.3.  I'm probably going to have to start using .on()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, live has been removed anyway in newer builds of jQuery, so I'd just get used to using it differently anyway.

```
$('body').on('click', '.ui-state-default', function(e) {
    $(".upload").show();
});
```

`body` can be replaced by anything guaranteed to be there on document ready that contains the `.ui-state-default` elements. Body will always be present, but perhaps you have something more specific you can use if you'd like.

Also, you probably don't really want to use 'click' on iOS, 'touchstart' might be a better choice. (but do some research rather than just dropping that in!)

Comment: If .live doesn't work, i doubt .on will work with the exact same code, considering it wasn't removed until 1.9

Comment: I kinda thought the same, but the bind version works, so this should too.

Comment: Most likely it's an event bubbling issue since the event has to bubble to be caught by a delegated event.

Comment: To prevent bubbling is it just .preventDefault();

Comment: @Blynn `e.stopPropagation()` will prevent the event from bubbling up - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/463828)

Answer (score 1):

Use .on() as .live() is deprecated, bind click and tap events:

```
$(document).on('click tap', '.ui-state-default', function(e) {
    $(".upload").show();
});
```

Comment: Is "tap" the same as click or is that have some new mobile event?

Comment: Sorry, i cannot test it. Could be tap, touchstart or other alias

Comment: For mobiles use [`vclick`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/), it's recommened by jQuery-Mobile. @Blynn